# pandas add row using lookup value

Tags: python, pandas, vlookup, lookup-tables

I have a dataframe with a model id and associated values. The columns are date, client_id, model_id, category1, category2, color, and price. I have a simple flask app where the user can select a model id and add to their "purchase" history. Based on the model id I would like to add a row to the dataframe and bring the associated values of category1, category2, color, and price.  What is the best way to do this using Pandas? I know in Excel I'd use a vlookup but I am unsure how to go about it using Python. Assume category1, category2, color, and price are unique to each model id.

```
client_id = input("ENTER Model ID:  ")      
model_id = input("ENTER Model ID:  ")
def update_history(df, client_id, model_id):
        today=pd.to_datetime('today')
        #putting in tmp but just need to "lookup" these values from the original dataframe somehow
        df.loc[len(df)]=[today, client_id, model_id, today, 'tmp', 'tmp','tmp', 'tmp'] 
        return df
```

Answer (score 0):

Code below adds a new row with new values to an existing dataframe. The list of new values could be passed in to the function.

**Import libraries**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime
```

**Create sample dataframe**

```
model_id = ['M1', 'M2', 'M3']
today = ['2018-01-01', '2018-01-02', '2018-01-01']
client_id = ['C1', 'C2', 'C3']
category1 = ['orange', 'apple', 'beans']
category2 = ['fruit', 'fruit', 'grains']
df = pd.DataFrame({'today':today, 'model_id': model_id, 'client_id':client_id,
                   'category1': category1, 'category2':category2})
df['today'] = pd.to_datetime(df['today'])
df
```

[image]

**Function**

```
def update_history(df, client_id, model_id, category1, category2):
        today=pd.to_datetime('today')
        # Create a temp dataframe with new values. 
        # Column names in this dataframe should match the existing dataframe
        temp = pd.DataFrame({'today':[today], 'model_id': [model_id], 'client_id':[client_id],
                   'category1': [category1], 'category2':[category2]})
        df = df.append(temp)
        return df
```

**Call function to append a row with new values to existing dataframe**

```
update_history(df, client_id='C4', model_id='M4', category1='apple', category2='fruit')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could try this. In case you are appending more than one row at a time, appending a dictionary to list and then appending them at once to a dataframe is faster.

```
modelid = ['MOD1', 'MOD2', 'MOD3']
today = ['2018-07-15', '2018-07-18', '2018-07-20']
clients = ['CLA', 'CLA', 'CLB']
cat_1 = ['CAT1', 'CAT2', 'CAT3']
cat_2 = ['CAT11', 'CAT12', 'CAT13']

mdf = pd.DataFrame({"model_id": modelid, "today": today, "client_id": clients, "cat_1":cat_1, "cat_2":cat_2})

def update_history(df, client_id, model_id):
    today = pd.to_datetime('today')
    row = df[df.model_id==model_id].iloc[0]
    rows_list = []
    dict = {"today":today, "client_id":client_id,
        "model_id":model_id,"cat_1":row["cat_1"],
        "cat_2":row["cat_2"]}
    rows_list.append(dict)
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(rows_list)
    df = df.append(df2) 
    return df



mdf = update_history(mdf,"CLC","MOD1")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up doing.  I still think there is a more elegant solution, so please let me know!

```
#create dataframe
modelid = ['MOD1', 'MOD2', 'MOD3']
today = ['2018-07-15', '2018-07-18', '2018-07-20']
clients = ['CLA', 'CLA', 'CLB']
cat_1 = ['CAT1', 'CAT2', 'CAT3']
cat_2 = ['CAT11', 'CAT12', 'CAT13']

mdf = pd.DataFrame({"model_id": modelid, "today": today, "client_id": clients, "cat_1":cat_1, "cat_2":cat_2})
#reorder columns
mdf = mdf[['cat_1', 'cat_2', 'model_id', 'client_id', 'today']] 

#create lookup table
lookup=mdf[['cat_1','cat_2','model_id']]
lookup.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)

#get values
client_id = input("ENTER Client ID:  ")      
model_id = input("ENTER Model ID:  ")

#append model id to list
model_id_lst=[]
model_id_lst.append(model_id)

today=pd.to_datetime('today')

#grab associated cat_1, and cat_2 from lookup table
temp=lookup[lookup['model_id'].isin(model_id_lst)]
out=temp.values.tolist()
out[0].extend([client_id, today])

#add this as a row to the df
mdf.loc[len(mdf)]=out[0]
```

Comment: Do you need a separate lookup table? Your lookup table here is just a subset of the original dataframe. You could do away with it altogether and look up the values in the original dataframe. One potential issue in both your solution and the other option is that there might be a incoming model_id, that isn't present in the dataframes.